# How set Android Alert Dilog with multi View

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a AlertDialog with a setView, and I want to to change the setView when an click set in button next

```
public void dd(View view){
    LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_1,null);

           final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
            builder.setTitle("HI");
            builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
            builder.setView(R.layout.layout_1);
            Button next = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button3);
            next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    builder.setView(R.layout.layout_2);

                                      }
            });
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: @naXa: I believe `plz` constitutes a heavily modified version of English known as "txtspk". It is well worth studying, even if people are likely to get downvoting for believing that typing "please" constitutes significant effort `:-)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change layout in builder. In the builder you can only set an initial dialog layout.

In order to make multi-step alert dialog try to place all steps into `layout1` and show/hide them on button Next/Previous click. Use `ViewGroup step1 = (ViewGroup) dialog.findViewById(R.id.step1);` to get views inside dialog.